# How to select multiple dates in mutate argument and making multiple columns

Tags: r

I'm running code to make a dataframe for prediction of different start times that birders would go out and make observations.

the code I am using is this:

```
pred_surface_eff <- pred_surface %>% 
  mutate(observation_date = ymd(str_glue("{max_lc_year}-06-01")),
         year = year(observation_date),
         day_of_year = yday(observation_date),
         time_observations_started = t_peak,
         duration_minutes = 60,
         effort_distance_km = 1,
         number_observers = 1)
```

I want a function that can create dates from 2010-06-01; to 2010-09-30; that runs with the code above by adding all of those extra data as separate columns in the dataframe `pred_surface_eff`, with the year not changing (in this case as its only 2010), but `observation_date` and `day_of_year` keep adding until the last day is met in the observation date.

for example:

```
$ id                            <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...
$ longitude                     <dbl> -77.27730, -77.2511...
$ latitude                      <dbl> 37.24792, 37.24792,...
$ year                          <dbl> 2019, 2019, 2019, 2...
$ pland_00_water                <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_01_evergreen_needleleaf <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_02_evergreen_broadleaf  <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_03_deciduous_needleleaf <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_04_deciduous_broadleaf  <dbl> 0.0000000, 0.500000...
$ pland_05_mixed_forest         <dbl> 0.0000000, 0.000000...
$ pland_06_closed_shrubland     <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_07_open_shrubland       <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_08_woody_savanna        <dbl> 0.5000000, 0.500000...
$ pland_09_savanna              <dbl> 0.5000000, 0.000000...
$ pland_10_grassland            <dbl> 0.0000000, 0.000000...
$ pland_11_wetland              <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_12_cropland             <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_13_urban                <dbl> 0.0000000, 0.000000...
$ pland_14_mosiac               <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ pland_15_barren               <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
$ elevation_median              <dbl> 39.95145, 41.77207,...
$ elevation_sd                  <dbl> 3.751318, 2.779185,...
$ observation_date              <date> 2019-06-15, 2019-0...
$ observation_date2             <date> 2019-06-16, 2019-0...
$ observation_date3             <date> 2019-06-17, 2019-0...
.
.
.
$ observation_date[last]        <date> 2019-09-30, 2019-0...
$ day_of_year                   <dbl> 121, 121, 121, 121,...
$ day_of_year2                  <dbl> 122, 122, 122, 122,...
.
.
.
$ day_of_year[last]             <dbl> 274, 274, 274, 274,...
$ time_observations_started     <dbl> 5.095745, 5.095745,...
$ duration_minutes              <dbl> 60, 60, 60, 60, 60,...
$ effort_distance_km            <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
$ number_observers              <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...
```

randomly selected reproducible code :

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50), id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), longitude = c(-77.2772962446392, 
-77.2772962446392, -77.2772962446392, -77.2772962446392, -77.2772962446392, 
-77.2772962446392, -77.2772962446392, -77.2772962446392, -77.2772962446392, 
-77.2772962446392, -77.2511245047927, -77.2511245047927, -77.2511245047927, 
-77.2511245047927, -77.2511245047927, -77.2511245047927, -77.2511245047927, 
-77.2511245047927, -77.2511245047927, -77.2511245047927, -77.30827104646, 
-77.30827104646, -77.30827104646, -77.30827104646, -77.30827104646, 
-77.30827104646, -77.30827104646, -77.30827104646, -77.30827104646, 
-77.30827104646, -77.2821065387109, -77.2821065387109, -77.2821065387109, 
-77.2821065387109, -77.2821065387109, -77.2821065387109, -77.2821065387109, 
-77.2821065387109, -77.2821065387109, -77.2821065387109, -77.2559420309617, 
-77.2559420309617, -77.2559420309617, -77.2559420309617, -77.2559420309617, 
-77.2559420309617, -77.2559420309617, -77.2559420309617, -77.2559420309617, 
-77.2559420309617), latitude = c(37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 
37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 
37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 
37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 
37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 
37.2479166633251, 37.2479166633251, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 
37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 
37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 
37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 
37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 
37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 
37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 
37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936, 37.2270833299936
), year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2019, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2010, 
2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to do with that selection?

if you just want to subset your dataframe to those date ranges you could do something like

```
years_to_select <- c(2010:2019)
days_to_select <- c(122:153) #adjust to days you actually want

ebird_split <- ebird_split[ebird_split$year %in% years_to_select,]
ebird_split <- ebird_split[ebird_split$day_of_year %in% days_to_select,]
```